# perf_counter is returning wrong time

Tags: python, time

I ran this simple code:

```
import time
print(time.perf_counter())
```

But for some reason, the output is 9851.549930951.
The code takes less than a second to run, and I am not using `perf_counter_ns`. This is a problem in other programs too. `perf_counter` outputs 9000+ instead of 0.9 for the number of seconds it takes for a thread to finish the execution. The output is always quick and yet the answer is always 9000+ like in 9851.549930951.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you read the documentation?  [time.perf_counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)

> Return the value (in fractional seconds) of a performance counter, i.e. a clock with the highest available resolution to measure a short duration. It does include time elapsed during sleep and is system-wide. **The reference point of the returned value is undefined, so that only the difference between the results of two calls is valid**. (emphasis mine)

So you do:

```
import time

start = time.perf_counter()

# ....

print (time.perf_counter() - start)
```

To get better performance measurements (avg of multiple runs) you may want to look into [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I was following a book and some tutorials online and there didn't seem to be any mention of using a separate variable that is initialized with perf_counter() upon the execution. This does seem to do the job. Thanks again for the links as well, I will study them thoroughly.